# How to use channels to gather response from various goroutines

Tags: go, concurrency, coroutine, goroutine

I am new to Golang and I have a task that I have implemented using `WaitGroup`, and `Mutex` which I would like to convert to use `Channels` instead.

A very brief description of the task is this: spurn as many go routines as needed to processes a result and in the main go routine wait and collect all the results.

The implementation I have using `WaitGroup`, and `Mutex` is as follows:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

func process(input int, wg *sync.WaitGroup, result *[]int, lock *sync.Mutex) *[]int {
    defer wg.Done()
    defer lock.Unlock()

    rand.Seed(time.Now().UnixNano())
    n := rand.Intn(5)
    time.Sleep(time.Duration(n) * time.Second)
    lock.Lock()
    *result = append(*result, input * 10)

    return result
}

func main() {

    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    var result []int
    var lock sync.Mutex
    for i := range []int{1,2,3,4,5} {
        wg.Add(1)
        go process(i, &wg, &result, &lock)
    }
}
```

How do I replace the memory synchronization with the usage of `Mutex` to one that uses `Channels`?

My main problem is I am not sure how to determine the final go routine that is processing the final task and hence have that one be the one to close the `channel`. The idea is that by closing the `channel` the main go routine can loop over the `channel`, retrieve the results and when it sees the `channel` has been closed, it moves on.

It could also be that the approach to close the channel is the wrong one in this scenario, hence why I am asking here.

How would a more experienced go programmer solve this problem using `channels`?

Comment: Closing the channel is correct. Because you have multiple senders, you still need the WaitGroup, and one additional goroutine that closes the channel once the WaitGroup is done.

Comment: Create a channel and pass it to `process` so that it can send results. Use another routine to wait on the `WaitGroup` and then close the channel. Meanwhile, in main, read results from the channel using `range`.

Comment: @hmm mind sketching this out in code in the answer? Thanks

Comment: not related to your question, but some advice. Using the `rand` package's pre-made rng among many goroutines will cause contention over the rng. For more performance (if required for your application), instantiate a new rng in each goroutine with `rand.New(rand.NewSource( yourSeed ))`. Also, there's no need to "reseed" the pre-made rng inside each goroutine--just seed it once at the beginning of your program.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a solution using `WaitGroup` instead of waiting for a fixed number of results.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

func process(input int, wg *sync.WaitGroup, resultChan chan<- int) {
    defer wg.Done()

    rand.Seed(time.Now().UnixNano())
    n := rand.Intn(5)
    time.Sleep(time.Duration(n) * time.Second)

    resultChan <- input * 10
}

func main() {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup

    resultChan := make(chan int)

    for i := range []int{1,2,3,4,5} {
        wg.Add(1)
        go process(i, &wg, resultChan)
    }

    go func() {
        wg.Wait()
        close(resultChan)
    }()

    var result []int
    for r := range resultChan {
        result = append(result, r)
    }

    fmt.Println(result)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I change your code to use the channel. there are many other ways to use the channel.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
    "time"
)

func process(input int, out chan<- int) {
    rand.Seed(time.Now().UnixNano())
    n := rand.Intn(5)
    time.Sleep(time.Duration(n) * time.Second)
    out <- input * 10
}

func main() {
    var result []int
    resultChan := make(chan int)
    items := []int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}

    for _, v := range items {
        go process(v, resultChan)
    }

    for i := 0; i < len(items); i++ {
        res, _ := <-resultChan
        result = append(result, res)
    }

    close(resultChan)
    fmt.Println(result)
}
```

**Update: (comment's answer)**

if items count is unknown you need to signal the main to finish. otherwise "deadlock", you can create a channel to signal the main function to finish. also, you can use `sync.waiteGroup`.

for panic in Goroutine, you can use defer and recover to handle errors . and you can create an error channel ore you can use `x/sync/errgroup`.

There are so many solutions. and it depends on your problem. so there is no specific way to use goroutine, channel, and...

Comment: This solution makes use of the knowledge that the number of iteration is known. ie by using len(items) how will the be approached in case this number is not known?

Comment: also what happens if there is a panic in one of the go routines? won't it through off the loop?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a sample snippet where I am using a slice of channels instead of waitgroups to perform a fork-join:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

type cStruct struct {
    resultChan chan int
    errChan    chan error
}

func process(i int) (v int, err error) {
    v = i
    return
}

func spawn(i int) cStruct {
    r := make(chan int)
    e := make(chan error)
    go func(i int) {
        defer close(r)
        defer close(e)
        v, err := process(i)
        if err != nil {
            e <- err
            return
        }
        r <- v
        return
    }(i)
    return cStruct{
        r,
        e,
    }
}

func main() {
    //have a slice of channelStruct
    var cStructs []cStruct
    nums := []int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
    for _, v := range nums {
        cStruct := spawn(v)
        cStructs = append(cStructs, cStruct)
    }
    //All the routines have been spawned, now iterate over the slice:
    var results []int
    for _, c := range cStructs {
        rChan, errChan := c.resultChan, c.errChan
        select {
        case r := <-rChan:
            {
                results = append(results, r)
            }
        case err := <-errChan:
            {
                if err != nil {
                    os.Exit(1)
                    return
                }
            }
        }

    }
    //All the work should be done by now, iterating over the results
    for _, result := range results {
        fmt.Println("Aggregated result:", result)
    }
}
```